# How can I crawl values of variable sub-elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I'm writing a crawler using node.js for study, and crawling data for future use as well. I know how to crawl a single element in the pages, but I couldn't figure out how to get the value of variable child-elements after a whole days's study.

Here is the part of HTML which I want to crawl. Each sub-element of 'attrgroup' has different number of

```
<p class="attrgroup">
<span><b>4</b>BR / <b>1</b>Ba</span>
<span><b>1200</b>ft<sup>2</sup></span>
<span>duplex</span> 
<span>laundry on site</span> 
<span>street parking</span>
<br><span>cats are OK - purrr</span></p>
```

Here is my code

```
            topics = topics.map(function (topicPair) {

                var topicUrl = topicPair[0];
                var topicHtml = topicPair[1];
                var $ = cheerio.load(topicHtml);
                return ({
//[1]I got correct value,such as duplex, using following clauses.
                  att1: $('.attrgroup').children().eq(0).text().trim(),
                  att2: $('.attrgroup').children().eq(1).text().trim(),
                  att3: $('.attrgroup').children().eq(2).text().trim(),
//[2]I want all of them,but.each function doesn't return the correct data
                  atts: $('.attrgroup').children().each(function(){
                    $(this).text()
                  }),
                });
            });
```

I got result like this:

```
att1: '4BR / 1Ba',
att2: '1200ft2',
att3: 'duplex'
atts:  { '0': [Object],
       '1': [Object],
       '2': [Object],
       '3': [Object],
       '4': [Object],
       '5': [Object],
       options: [Object],
       _root: [Object],
       length: 7,
       prevObject: [Object] },
```

Currently, I know the reason might be $(this),a jquery object. I tried to convert it to DOM object which didn't work either.
Could any one help me correct that part of my code, or tell me how to fix it. It doesn't have to use each method, any method works is welcoming. Or a hint will help a lot as well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should write a [recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) to walk the DOM tree and extract the text content.

Comment: By looking at your code, what do you expect the each function to do? $.each iterates over the matched set and returns the set to be chainable. I guess you would like to do something like `Array.prototype.reduce.call($('.attrgroup').children(), function (prev,cur) {return prev + $(cur).text()}, "");`

See [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) MDN doc, or just use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I'd like to return all the child elements of attrgroups, while these attrgroups have different number of child elements. I don't really know how to use the method you mentioned. Anyway,it has been resolved now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
return (function () {

    var object = {};

    $('.attrgroup').children().each(function(i, element){
        object["att" + i] = $(element).text().trim();
    });

    return object;

})();
```

Comment: Perfect,that's exactly what I what to do.Thank you very much.